# JSTREE script execute asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jstree

I Have implemented **[JSTREE](http://www.jstree.com/)** on my project everything work fine but recently I faced the issue which even though I manage to fix the concept of it is still unclear to me .

Here What I meant ?

the **JSTREE** Code is Written in [jquery](http://jquery.com/) **document ready function** 
 Like this

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() { 
>   $("#someid").jstree( { 
>
>     "json_data" : {
>       "data" : [{
>         "attr" : { "id" : "root" },
>         "data" : {
>           "title" : "Root",
>           "attr" : { "id" : "root","href" : "#" ,"class" : "jstree-clicked" }
>         },
>         "children" : [
>               {
>               "attr" : {"id" : "node-1"},
>               "data" : {
>                 "title" : "Node-1",
>                 "attr" : {"id" : "node-1" ,"href": "#" }
>               },
>               "children": [
>
>               ],
>               "state" : "closed"
>             },
>
>               {
>               "attr" : {"id" : "node-2"},
>               "data" : {
>                 "title" : "Node-2",
>                 "attr" : {"id" : "node-2" ,"href": "#" }
>               },
>               "children": [
>
>               ],
>               "state" : "closed"
>             },
>
>               {
>               "attr" : {"id" : "node-3"},
>               "data" : {
>                 "title" : "Node-3",
>                 "attr" : {"id" : "node-3" ,"href": "#" }
>               },
>               "children": [
>
>               ],
>               "state" : "closed"
>             },
>
>               {
>               "attr" : {"id" : "node-4"},
>               "data" : {
>                 "title" : "Node-4",
>                 "attr" : {"id" : "node-4" ,"href": "#" }
>               },
>               "children": [
>
>               ],
>               "state" : "closed"
>             },
>
>               {
>               "attr" : {"id" : "node-5"},
>               "data" : {
>                 "title" : "Node-5",
>                 "attr" : {"id" : "node-5" ,"href": "#" }
>               },
>               "children": [
>
>               ],
>               "state" : "closed"
>             }
>      ],
>      // the method where the ajax request will be sent to get thejson data to build the tree
>     "ajax" : {
>       "url" : "/my_url/tree",
>       "data" : function (focus_element) {
>         return { node : focus_element.attr ? focus_element.attr("id") : 0 };
>       }
>     }
>   },
>
>   "themes" : {
>     "theme" : "classic",
>     "dots" : true,
>     "icons" : true
>   },
>   "plugins" : ["themes",  "json_data" ,"ui"]
>
> })
> ```

There is a **another jquery document ready** function on the page **which will click the** anchor node **created but the above jstree** .

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>  $("a#node-1").click()
> ```
>
> })

Now The problem come when the page is load the tree is constructed all 
the tree is  constructed but the **node-1** anchor link is not getting clicked .

Debugging it I found That the **console.log always present me and empty array** for a#node-1 which is very weird.

I  put **alert box in second document.ready function** to see  whether the tree is constructed when I'm requesting for the node. like this

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> alert("JSTREE SHOULD BE CREATED BY NOW");
>
> $("a#node-1").click()
> ```
>
> })

But to my astonishment the when the **alert popped up JSTREE was still build the tree .**

With some decent understanding of javascript I know that script tag on the page are **synchronous in nature** i.e  the second script on the page execute only when the first execute

This make me believe **is JSTREE running asynchronously** .If yes Can please any one share some light on it .

By the Way I manage to achieve the same using **jstree load handler**

> $("#someid").bind("loaded.jstree",
>
> ```
>    function() {   
>        $("a#node-1").click();   
>        })
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your question has an interesting answer*: I just found out that the code in jquery.jstree.js (jsTree 1.0-rc3), uses setTimer(...) to call .init() on the nodes, i.e. is asynchronous. I also used jsTree 1.0-rc1 in other project and it is synchronous.

I am afraid you won't find this documented as it is an implementation detail: it depends on the version you use.

As suggested by others, use the event mechanism in jstree to achieve what you want.
On the other hand, Jurgen was right about the structure of the DOM.

(*) I browsed thru Github to see the original code, it seems the change happened in 2011. Before that you had:

**jsTree 1.0-rc1**
https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/0b8ebb2ba468b4c81e3c7645a9335584ddab41f5/jquery.jstree.js

```
line 59: instances[instance_id]._init();
```

whereas now,

**jStree 1.0-rc3**
https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/v.pre1.0/jquery.jstree.js

```
line 162: setTimeout(function() { instances[instance_id].init(); }, 0);
```

Comment: That It thanks Caya there you have it I was right in my belief that jstree was executing "asynchronously" (For God damn It would doomed all little knowledge I had,had it would have been executing synchronously) Thank @caya accepting  the answer and awarding the bounty

Answer (score 0):

Through reading JSTree docs I found one interesting note:
On page http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data in first code part noted that

```
// `state` and `children` are only used for NON-leaf nodes
```

But you trying to use them as nodes that has child nodes. Maybe this causes your issue.

Comment: No Brother the node which contain "state" and "children" options above  are "non-leafy" node (they have their childrens associated with them(not loaded using ajax by the way))which I deliberately removed from the above code for the sake of reducing the code and cleanliness.

Comment: This may help. Also can you try to put $("a#node-1").click(); in the same $(document).ready function where jsTree initializes and check whether your bug continues to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks @CoolEsh but I tried that Hence I pasting the Code so that you can get the thorough idea of the same

Answer (score 0):

Edit. Just checked the doc, my first guess was correct, removed the rest.

The id will be applied to an `<li>` which contains an `<a>`. Do

```
$("li#node-1 > a").click()
```

instead. Your CSS selector is wrong and will never match, this has nothing to do with async tree behavior.

Edit:

Now if your tree is contstructed async and you need to wait for its loaded event, you can do this with the following
code *before* you initialize the tree, or you might lose the loaded event due to a timing race condition:

```
jQuery("#someid").bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
    $("li#node-1 > a").click();
    # or:
    $(this).jstree("open_node", "node-1");
});
```

If you just want to have the node opened on load, and not do anything complex
otherwise, you can use the initially_open init parameter to set intial opened nodes too
without fiddling with events at all.

Comment: Nope That too Didn't Work, Yes The CSS selector will never find the node-1 anchor tag (as I noticed that the 2nd document.ready is executed while the 1st document.ready is still constructing the "jstree") and that is question how come the second document.ready is executed when the first document.ready  is processing as script on page exhibits synchronous nature. Any way pasting the code for better understanding of same.

Comment: Edit: Explained order/timing of needed event registrations for asyn code init.